# passing parameters from unix to pl sql

Tags: unix, plsql

I have a dumb problem.
From a ksh I'm connecting to sql plus to execute some query.
I want to pass 2 parameters from unix to pl sql.
I found some stuff but it does not works.

UNIX:

```
sqlplus -L $ORA_CONNECT @"$FIC_REQ" $1 $2
```

PLSQL:

```
   DECLARE

     param1 := $1;
     param2 := $2;
BEGIN

 SELECT * from MYTABLE where field1=param1 and field2=param2;

END
```

Any idea how to do it ?

---

Actually, I got it.

I must use a double dollar in plsql, like

param1:=$$1
param2:=$$2

Comment: Please don't add edit answers into your questions. You should post an answer containing your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use %1 and %2, not the $ (dollar) symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus -L $ORA_CONNECT @"$FIC_REQ" param1 param2

BEGIN

SELECT * from MYTABLE where field1=&1 and field2=&2;
```